# Change text object crystal report during run time with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have problem with crystal report. This is the scenario.

I want to print to printer from vb.net --> crystal Report --> Printer.

There is one blank field called DOType. When i run the program, i want to print with 1 Original (blank field called DOType was changed into "ORIGINAL") and 2 copies (blank field called DOType was changed into "COPY")

Here is my code :

```
Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
    cryRpt.Load("RASManualDeliveryOrder.rpt")
    Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As ParameterDiscreteValue
    Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
    Dim crParameterFieldDefintion As ParameterFieldDefinition
    Dim crParameterValues As ParameterValues

    crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
    crParameterFieldDefintion = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("@DOType")
    crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefintion.CurrentValues
    crParameterDiscreteValue = New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterDiscreteValue
    crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = "ORIGINAL"
    crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
    crParameterFieldDefintion.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)
    Form1.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
    Form1.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    Form1.Show()
```

An error occured while in "crParameterFieldDefintion = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("@DOType")"

This the error shown : Invalid Index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX)

Any idea ?

Comment: Specify What Error you are getting

Comment: i've changed it already

Comment: name of parameter is not correct crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("@DOType") @??

Comment: i have change it into the right name. But it still can't. Now i change the code into : 
     Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
        cryRpt.Load("C:\Users\FenFen\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Kline_\Kline_\RasManualDeliveryOrder2.rpt")
        Dim myTextObjectOnReport As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject
        myTextObjectOnReport = CType(cryRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects.Item("TypeDO"), CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)
        myTextObjectOnReport.Text = "ORIGINAL"
       Form1.Show()
The error didn't come but still that text object still blank

Comment: try directcast instead of CType

Comment: can you show the syntax ? i'm still newbie in crystal report.

Comment: you syntax is right just replace CInt with DirectCast

Comment: it still didn't appear. :(